# In MFC how to hide tooltip of CEdit

Tags: mfc

I added an edit control to my GUI with the style ES_NUMBER. When I try to enter a character then a tooltip appears with text "Unacceptable Character".

Is there a possibility to hide this tooltip?

Comment: Why do you want to hide it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to derive a class from `CEdit` and handle `EM_SHOWBALLOONTIP` message:

**Class header:**

```
class CNoTooltipEdit: public CEdit
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CNoTooltipEdit)

public:
    CNoTooltipEdit();
    virtual ~CNoTooltipEdit();

protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    LRESULT OnShowTip(WPARAM w, LPARAM l);
};
```

**Class Implementation:**

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CNoTooltipEdit, CEdit)

CNoTooltipEdit::CNoTooltipEdit()
{

}

CNoTooltipEdit::~CNoTooltipEdit()
{
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CNoTooltipEdit, CEdit)
    ON_MESSAGE(EM_SHOWBALLOONTIP, &CNoTooltipEdit::OnShowTip)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

LRESULT CNoTooltipEdit::OnShowTip(WPARAM w, LPARAM l)
{
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to turn off the sound notification as well?

Comment: These beeps are coming from the CEdit implementation (in common control dll).
When you exceed the text limit or enter invalid character (alpha for numeric control), it calls MessageBeep().
You could derive your own class from CEdit and implement WM_CHAR handler which will filter invalid characters and will NOT pass them to the base class.